# compare a command line argument with or statment to different strings python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I need to compare my 2 command line argument to the see if it doesn't equal `"tcp"` or `"udp"`.  I know you can use the or statement with `==` but I am having trouble adapting it to `!=` in a statement.

```
protocol = sys.argv[2]

if protocol != "tcp" or protocol != "udp":    
     print" error"
     sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, the problem is in your logic, the answer will ALWAYS be either NOT one or the other.  Use this code:

```
if protocol not in ['tcp','udp']:
   print "error"
   sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `in`?

```
if protocol not in ("tcp", "udp"):
    print" error"
    sys.exit()
```

FYI, instead of using `sys.argv` and validating script arguments manually, use `argparse` module from stdlib. Take a look at `choices` argument of `add_argument` method, [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method):

> choices - A container of the allowable values for the argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is case of [DeMorgan's law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

If you have `q = not (a or b)`, to change it to use `not a` and `not b`, you need to change the operator: `q = (not a) and (not b)`

In your case, `a` is `protocol == "tcp"`, so `protocol != "tcp"` is `not a`, and similarly for `"udp"`, and `b`.